# linux и windows7 интернет один - скорость разная?

Tags: linux, windows-7

Очень интересует вопрос, как сделать такую же скорость на w7. При использовании linux скорость скачивания была от 300кб/с до 500, а на w7 110кб/с.качал один и тот же файл на рутрекер.орг

Answer (score 1):

А если через netstat -na глянуть, то никакой процесс больше ничего не качает? Вдруг, винда обновления тянет или ещё что-то такое.По предыдущему ответу: для линукса есть как минимум касперский, и он точно не единственный антивирус.Деб - это Debian, судя по всему.

Answer (score 0):

юзай антивирусы, вирусов на линуксе их нет, а на винде достаточно...

пока сидел на винде скорость выше 3-5 редко поднималась, сейчас на дебе, 11-12 метров с рутора постоянно.

Comment: В смысле юзать? Использовать антивирусы? что такое дебе?))

Answer (score 0):

speedtest.net по поводу реальной скорости.

Не грешите на форточки. Мож всё таки дело с torrent client?

W7x64 BitTorrent второй год. Проблем не замечено. Забирает весь канал 100мб по возможности. Балансировка трафика адекватная.